# docker connection string edit dynamically while running

Tags: docker

is it possible to give the new mysql RDS databse while running the docker image? We have run the docker command with new database but its not updated.

docker run --expose 80 -i -d -P  --name test5  "mysqlconnection":"server=<sererip/dnsname>;port=3333;database=dbname;uid=admin;pwd=admin123;Connect Timeout=300;"

Comment: That depends on the image the container is running.  You can't change the command-line options or environment variables on a Docker container (or any other process) after it's started.

Answer (score 0):

you can set it to an environment variable, either in Dockerfile or by using the -e flag. for more [info](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/docker-container-environment-variables)